# Can no longer boot into Windows 7

Tags: 11.10, windows, grub2, boot-failure

I have a laptop on which I had Windows 7 installed on. Later I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a new partition (sda7).

Somehow it magically moved to sda6 and the grub loader freaked out. Then I booted with my live cd of Ubuntu and downloaded ubuntus own boot-repair and ran the recomended program. When I now restarted I could boot into Ubuntu but not Windows, it just says:
unknown filesystem
grub>

**Edit** I trind to run the Ubuntu live cd and install it and I no longer get the option where it asks if I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. It says that no other operativesystem wap found. But if I mount C and My other partitions, all files is still there.

More info here http://paste.ubuntu.com/716521/

**EDIT2**
I managed to get my computer to recognize Windows 7 again and I updated grub via boot-repair and there it is on the boot menu. Now the only problem is that when I trying too boot it, it says: "Unknow filesystem" and then the grub resque thing.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/719930/

Am I on the right path?

Comment: It appears (from your link) that the windows boot sector used to be on sda2 (which is the active partition) and now grub was installed onto the same location (boot sector of sda2), thus overwriting the windows boot sector. It's not clear from the information you give whether there is a copy of the Windows boot sector somewhere on your hard disk. You may have to repair/reinstall your Windows OS.

Comment: Oh ok...When I mount C i can se a folder named Boot and a folder named oldbooot, could this be something? And also I don't have a recovery cd but I have a recovery partition. In the grub menu at boot there's a option Windows Recovery Environment (/dev/sda1) (sda1 is the recovery partition), Windows 7 is no longer an option. But when I choose to boot Windows Recovery, I get into windows but it only shows me a big ugly error screen and at the top it says something like Missing C:/RECOVERY.dat I think.

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Though by some miracle I managed to get into the recovery without seeing the error msg, instead I got a dialog box telling me I can restore, but it also said that all my files would be deleted. I got scared and restarted the computer, since then all I see is the error msg. But I have to ask, does it mean all my files or only the files on the C partition?

Comment: I managed to get my computer to recognize Windows 7 again and I updated grub via boot-repair and there it is on the boot menu. Now the only problem is that when I trying too boot it, it says: "Unknow filesystem" and then the grub resque thing.

Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 1):

[Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is often useful is situations like these!

It can restore a botched Windows MBR in a heartbeat.

After that's done, you need to be able to load Windows from Grub.

To do so, just boot into the Ubuntu Live CD and run a few commands.

First, identify which is the **Ubuntu** partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Next, mount it (replacing sda2 with the appropriate partition number):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

And finally, reinstall Grub (replacing sda with the appropriate hard drive):

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Now, reboot, and run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should detect your Windows installation and add it to the Grub menu.