# My battery died, and now Ubuntu won't start

Tags: 10.04, grub2

I was working on Ubuntu 10.04, then the battery died. I plugged in the charger, and now Ubuntu won't start. It keeps showing an error screen similar to the following:

[image: GNU Grub error screen]

Except that the grub version is `GNU GRUB version 1.98-1ubuntu12` and the background is black, because I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Taken from [this forum post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/error-of-grub-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-660334/), try running the commands `find /grub/stage2` and `find /boot/grub/stage2`. One of those should give output -- please update your answer with that output.

Comment: I don't know what caused this problem or how to fix it, but if you need to get to your files on Ubuntu, you can [run Ubuntu from a CD or USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and access your hard drive that way.

Answer (score 1):

Boot with a Live CD, and check your Ubuntu partition with Gparted.

To do this:

- Right-click your Ubuntu partiton, and click Unmount, if the partition is mounted
- Right-click your Ubuntu partiton, and click Check
- Click on the green checkmark button ("Apply All Operations")

This will check for and fix any filesystem errors on your Ubuntu partition.

If the previous steps didn't work, then refer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/97184/40421) for easy instructions on how to reinstall Grub.